# Is it possible to make an NSObject conform to a protocol ? and if it, how ? -Take it serious

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, protocols, nsobject

My question may seem strange, but i wanna to get this idea around Stackers' minds, in my work i just noticed that every protocol is conformed by a class all the time, i wondered about the possibility to make a simple object conforms to protocols too, and if not (and almost not ), why not ??

Appreciate your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to protocol conformance:

- the object must respond to the required messages in the protocol definition
- the object must return `YES` when asked whether it conforms to the protocol

So, can we arrange for an instance of `NSObject` to satisfy those two conditions? Yes. In fact, there are at least two ways to do so. First, let's make *all* instances of `NSObject` conform to the protocol. What we do is to define the protocol methods in a category on `NSObject`, which solves the first part. Then we "swizzle" (which means using the [`class_replaceMethod()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) runtime function) `-[NSObject conformsToProtocol:]`, returning `YES` for our interesting protocol.

Now let's imagine that you want to make a *specific* instance of `NSObject` conform to the protocol. This is slightly easier. First, create a subclass of `NSObject` that conforms to the protocol and implements the required methods; there's no need to override `-conformsToProtocol:` because the runtime library can see that this class conforms. Now, at runtime, take your `NSObject` instance and call [`object_setClass()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to switch its class to your conforming subclass.

Comment: There's another part of protocol conformance: `class_conformsToProtocol()`

Comment: Great answer , i consider this is a work around the main problem, it's working i admit that Subclassing and Categories are solutions for the problem, my target is if any dummy object anywhere (whatever class ) is defined to responds to the messages protocol define and defined also to say "YES" i conforms to this protocol , so no need to establish a class or subclass or category that acts as a blueprint for this object, you can call it "dynamic classing !! "
The way i am discussing now somehow a new one, but i think it's possible 

Appreciate your concern

Answer (score 0):

You can add protocols to classes at runtime, using the runtime function `class_addProtocol()`. However, doing so when the class does not implement all the methods of the protocol will likely lead to bad results.

Comment: you r right using the method    class_addProtocol() at runtime, but how could you define the methods required for this protocol conformance ? and what if this protocol has required methods ?

Comment: @Meseery: you can add methods to a class using `class_addMethod()`